# Creating a custom Abstract class of ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, class, android-arrayadapter, abstract

I'd like to create my own abstract version of ArrayAdapter which adds functionality of custom `Intent` Navigation and `Toast` popups among others.

Here is an example of my custom Activity:

```
public abstract class RBActivity extends Activity implements IActivity {

    private Navigator navigator;
    private Toaster toaster;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        navigator = new Navigator(this);
        toaster = new Toaster(this);
    }

    public Navigator navigate() {
        return navigator;
    }

    protected void popBurntToast(String msg) {
        toaster.popBurntToast(msg);
    }

    protected void popToast(String msg) {
        toaster.popToast(msg);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        navigator = null;
        toaster = null;
    }   
}
```

Then within my Activity's i simply extend from `RBActivity` instead of `Activity`. I then can call this.navigate().toSomeActivity(); using my `Navigator class` which has methods for easily creating intents to navigate around my application. I also have my own `RBListActivity` etc

Here is a sample method from my navigator class:

```
public void toSiteSubscribeActivity(Site _site) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SiteSubscribeActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putLong(Navigator.INTENT_KEY_CHANNEL_ID, _site.getIdSite());
    b.putString(Navigator.INTENT_KEY_CHANNEL_NAME, _site.getName());
    b.putString(Navigator.INTENT_KEY_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION, _site.getDescription());
    intent.putExtras(b);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Anyway, I want to also have a RBArrayAdapter<> but I'm not sure how to create a generic version which doesn't require i specify the class type within the <> braces ie,

```
public abstract class RBArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    private Navigator navigator;
    private Toaster toaster;

    public RBArrayAdapter(Activity _activity, int _layout, ArrayList<Article> _notes) {
        super(_activity, _layout, _notes);

        navigator = new Navigator(_activity);
        toaster = new Toaster(_activity);
    }


    public Navigator navigate() {
        return navigator;
    }   
}
```

I tried doing something like `public abstract class RBArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<?>` but it obviously doesn't work...

I guess in short, I'm asking how to accept a generic class type within  the pointy braces

Any help is really appreciated, Cheers

EDIT: ok after looking at ArrayAdapter.java (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) I think what i need is `ArrayAdapter<T>` Syntax. looking into that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need the syntax to make this work. Try this:

```
public abstract class RBArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    private Navigator navigator;
    private Toaster toaster;

    public RBArrayAdapter(Activity _activity, int _layout, ArrayList<T> _notes) {
        super(_activity, _layout, _notes);

        navigator = new Navigator(_activity);
        toaster = new Toaster(_activity);
    }


    public Navigator navigate() {
        return navigator;
    }   
}
```

Then you should be able to substitute any parameter you like for `<T>` when you instantiate your RBArrayAdapter subclass (something like this):

```
public class MyStringArrayAdapter extends RBArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyStringArrayAdapter(Activity _activity, int _layout, ArrayList<String> _notes) {
      super(_activity, _layout, _notes);
    }

}
```

Have fun.

Comment: Cheers yep I actually realised this after seeing how its done within ArrayAdapter.java (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) see edit

Comment: Yep, I saw your edit after I submitted my answer, but at that point I was committed. Besides, I don't need much of an excuse to write code. :) Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thank you working perfectly now just use something like this when using ArrayAdapters - `public class ChatArrayAdapter extends RBArrayAdapter<Article> implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener, ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {` works just like a bought one :P